# New wordpress site, want to incorporate an old php catalog

Tags: php, wordpress, migration, hosting

i'm completely new to migrating websites.
I made a new website for someone in wordpress but on the same url.
I migrated the hosting and changed the A-records. I do have the old site in backup (both files, and sql database.)
How would i go about hosting an old catalog that is made in php on a subsite?

Kind regards
Viktor.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set up the final site correctly with PHP + Mysql.
Then install the "duplicator" plugin on the Wordpress to Clone. Paste to the new ftp site the two files (installer.php and XXX.zip) and run it from the new site root url ([www.newdomain.com/installer.php](http://www.newdomain.com/installer.php))